# Not all terms work in ElasticSearch Query

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm not seeing the results I expected when using term searching as described by https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html

The ElasticSearch version is 2.3.2: Using this to create the data:

```
curl -XPUT http://myelastic:9201/myindex/mytype/90273504?pretty=true -d '{ "CLIENT_ID" : "000000001", "USER_TYPE" : "ABC"}'
curl -XPUT http://myelastic:9201/myindex/mytype/90273505?pretty=true -d '{ "CLIENT_ID" : "000000002", "USER_TYPE" : "ABC"}'
```

This query shows both records:

```
curl -D - -o - http://myelastic:9201/myindex/mytype/_search?pretty=true -H"Accept: application/json" -d '{ "query" : { "match_all" : { } } }'

{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "myindex",
      "_type" : "mytype",
      "_id" : "90273505",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source" : {
        "CLIENT_ID" : "000000002",
        "USER_TYPE" : "ABC"
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "myindex",
      "_type" : "mytype",
      "_id" : "90273504",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source" : {
        "CLIENT_ID" : "000000001",
        "USER_TYPE" : "ABC"
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

This query shows one record, as expected:

```
curl -D - -o - http://myelastic:9201/myindex/mytype/_search?pretty=true -H"Accept: application/json" \
    -d '{ "query" : { "bool" : { "should" : [ { "term" : { "CLIENT_ID" : "000000001" } } ] } } }'
```

But using a different term results in no records:

```
curl -D - -o - http://myelastic:9201/myindex/mytype/_search?pretty=true -H"Accept: application/json" \
    -d '{ "query" : { "bool" : { "should" : [ { "term" : { "USER_TYPE" : "ABC" } } ] } } }'
```

Ultimately I want to score records based on matches on multiple terms, starting with a selection on multiple terms like this:

```
curl -D - -o - http://myelastic:9201/myindex/mytype/_search?pretty=true -H"Accept: application/json" \
    -d '{ "query" : { "bool" : { "should" : [ { "term" : { "CLIENT_ID" : "000000001" } }, { "term" : { "USER_TYPE" : "ABC" } } ] } } }'
```

But right now I'm trying to understand why

```
curl -D - -o - http://myelastic:9201/myindex/mytype/_search?pretty=true -H"Accept: application/json" \
    -d '{ "query" : { "bool" : { "should" : [ { "term" : { "USER_TYPE" : "ABC" } } ] } } }'
```

returns no records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Standard analyzer
>
> The standard analyzer is the default analyzer that
>   Elasticsearch uses. It is the best general choice for analyzing text
>   that may be in any language. It splits the text on word boundaries, as
>   defined by the Unicode Consortium, and removes most punctuation.
>   **Finally, it lowercases all terms.**

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/analysis-intro.html#_built_in_analyzers

Try to search lower case text. I think it works with numbers because they have no case.

```
curl -D - -o - http://myelastic:9201/myindex/mytype/_search?pretty=true -H"Accept: application/json" \
    -d '{ "query" : { "bool" : { "should" : [ { "term" : { "USER_TYPE" : "abc" } } ] } } }'
```

[This thread could help](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-do-case-insensitive-search-on-terms/19790/3)

Comment: Thanks. I'll check out that link, too. Can you a summary to your answer as to why it works this way?

Comment: I have found exact peace from documentation

Comment: Excellent, thanks. It looks like I want `match`, not `term`.